# calculate returns in r given imported data from excel

Tags: r, csv, return

I'm new to R and I'm trying to get returns from a timeseries of S&P500 prices.
My original file is in csv format. I uploaded it using:

```
>sp500 <- read.csv2("sp500.csv")
```

and then, after uploading timeSeries package, tryied to run:

```
>rend <- returns(sp500)
```

But I get:

```
>Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

It seems to me that r read my file, not as an array of numbers, but as an array of strings and so it doesn't work math computation.
Anyone can help me and suggest me how to solve it?

thank you very much!

Comment: You should include at least a few lines of sp500.csv so that people know what you're looking at

Answer (score 0):

before calling `returns()`, you should first transform your `data.frame` into a `timeSeries`, for example:

```
sp500Series <- as.timeSeries(sp500)
```